# How to parse svgs with unquoted attributes in `svgo`?

Tags: svg, webpack, loader, webpack-plugin, svgo

When parsing using [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) or as part of webpack loader ([svgo-loader](https://github.com/rpominov/svgo-loader)) or plugin ([imagemin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-webpack-plugin)) that both use svgo, if you have svgs with unquoted attributes such as:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width=20px height=20px
```

The error: `Error in parsing SVG: Unquoted attribute value` is emitted.

Can svg's with unquoted attributes be used in all of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a loader to canonize xmls (including svgs) in webpack:

[xml-fix-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-fix-loader)

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: [
    { loader: 'file-loader' },
    { loader: 'svgo-loader' },
    { loader: 'xml-fix-loader' }
  ]
}
```

what it does in general is to use [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) to parse the xml unstrictly and then stringify it back to get a cononized xml (or svg).

This removes issues like unquoted attributes. so:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width=20px height=20px
```

becomes

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20px" height="20px"
```