# Error: postcss-svgo: Error in parsing SVG: Unquoted attribute value

Tags: postcss-loader

I'm trying to deploy my nuxt app on Heroku, but everytime I try to deploy it, I get this error message that reads the following:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/argon-design-system-free/assets/css/argon.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/argon-design-system-free/assets/css/argon.min.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: postcss-svgo: Error in parsing SVG: Unquoted attribute value
Line: 0
Column: 12
Char: \
    at promises.push.getSvgo.optimize.then.catch.error (C:\Sites\unsplash-app\node_modules\postcss-svgo\dist\index.js:95:19)
 @ ./node_modules/argon-design-system-free/assets/css/argon.min.css 4:14-147
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js
```

This error occurs every time I run the `yarn build` command to build my project.

In my project, I decided to use the free design system called [Argon Design](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/argon-design-system) and the error indicates that there is something wrong with its *argon.min.css* file and I don't know how I should proceed at this point.

To diagnose the issue, I tried installing the [xml-fix-loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699759/how-to-parse-svgs-with-unquoted-attributes-in-svgo) module onto my project, but it didn't help in resolving my issue. Am I supposed to do additional steps when I install it by any chance?

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: @DaveSottimano no, I tried a lot of things when I was trying to fix it, but I had to move on to other projects and didn't get a chance to come back to it. If you guys find out anything, let me know! Thanks.

Comment: I ended up removing the prettier (linter) from the project, I couldn't find any other solution that would let me build the production version.

Comment: @Student22 Did you resolve this issue ?